# In eslint hide errors with variables which are not used at this moment

Tags: vue.js, eslint

In my @vue/cli 4.1.1 app on installation in file .eslintrc.js I have options

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'off' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'off' : 'off'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
}
```

and it works ok for me, expect it shows error with variables which are not used at this moment

If there is a way to remove only this option, leaving the rest of options ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line : `'vue/no-unused-vars': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'`
This will disable the rule when developing but throw an error when you try to build for production.

If you to disable the rule anytime put this instead : `'vue/no-unused-vars': 'off'`

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'off' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'off' : 'off',
    'vue/no-unused-vars': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Could you please provide a link to all eslin keys?
In my app I use 2 files:
.env.production and .env.development
Have I to change condition as in you sample?